# Show that a set is not invariant

Tags: dynamical-systems

From my textbook (Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields). Consider the following system
\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  \dot{u} \\
  \dot{v} \\
  \dot{w}
\end{array}\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -(1+\sigma) & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -\beta
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  u \\
  v \\
  w
\end{array}\right)+
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
  -\frac{\sigma}{1+\sigma} (u+\sigma v)w \\
  \\
  \frac{1}{1+\sigma}(u+\sigma v)w \\
  \\
  (u+\sigma v)(u-v)
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

My textbook says: "u axis is not invariant because the equation for $\dot w$ includes the term $u^2$". It is not clear to me, maybe because I'm not English speaking. But I have made the following reasoning. If $v=w=0$ we have:

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  \dot{u} \\
  \dot{v} \\
  \dot{w}
\end{array}\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  0 \\
  0 \\
  u^2
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
from which

\begin{equation}
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  u \\
  v \\
  w
\end{array}\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
  u_0 \\
  v_0 \\
  u_0^2 t
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

If $u_0=1$ and $v_0=0$ then: $(u,v,w)^T=(1,0,t)^T$ that does not belong to the u axis for $t\neq 0$.

What do you think of my proceedings? Is my procedure right? I made ​​a mistake?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step "from which" is not quite right, since once you leave the $u$ axis, the derivative will no longer be as simple as $(0,0,u^2)$.

But on the other hand, you don't need a conclusion that strong; it's enough to note that since the derivative (evaluated on the $u$ axis) is not of the form $(\text{something},0,0)$, you are going to leave the $u$ axis immediately.